# How could I make this popup menu for web while working in EXPO?

Tags: expo, popupmenu

[image]

On press three dots. I would like to open an option container to handle further actions. How could I make as I am working on Expo for android, iOS and web app and this pop will be open in web only.

Comment: See the above image attached.

Answer (score 2):

finally, find my self an expo react native library react-native-popup-menu.

```
import { MenuProvider } from 'react-native-popup-menu';

export const App = () => (
  <MenuProvider>
    <YourApp />
  </MenuProvider>
);

import {
  Menu,
  MenuOptions,
  MenuOption,
  MenuTrigger,
} from 'react-native-popup-menu';

export const YourComponent = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    <Menu>
      <MenuTrigger text='Select action' />
      <MenuOptions>
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Save`)} text='Save' />
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Delete`)} >
          <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Delete</Text>
        </MenuOption>
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Not called`)} disabled={true} text='Disabled' />
      </MenuOptions>
    </Menu>
  </View>
);
```